# Problems with utf-8

Tags: android, utf-8

I'm getting an encrypted webservice from a client but it has text like this "&#211 ;" (intentionally space)

i tried use:

```
new String(string.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
new String(string.getBytes("UTF-8"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")
new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1")
```

i don't know what's happen here. This is the first time i have problems with utf-8.

Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably receiving encrypted bytes, not a string. Not all 8-bit byte arrays can be converted into a unicode string. The way to tell is to log the received bytes in hexadecimal format and examine them.

But the good news, don't try to convert the bytes to a string, just paid the byte array to the decryption function.